# Terraform attaching NIC to correct subnet id in Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a module that creates a vNet with 5 subnets. The module writes the id of each subnet to a variable using the block:

```
output "vnet_subnets" {
  description = "The ids of subnets created inside the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_subnet.subnet.*.id
}
```

I then output that to the state file using the block:

```
output "vnet_subnets" {
  value = module.virtual_network.vnet_subnets
}
```

In the state file, the output looks like this:

```
"vnet_subnets": {
      "value": [
        "/subscriptions/<my_sub_id>/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/GatewaySubnet",
        "/subscriptions/<my_sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/VDMS",
        "/subscriptions/<my_sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/external",
        "/subscriptions/<my_sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/internal",
        "/subscriptions/<my_sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/management"
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string",
          "string",
          "string",
          "string",
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

I have a virtual machine deployment that I want to use the vnet state file as a data source so that I can assign the VM to the correct subnet. My question is, how do I find the correct subnet in the `vnet_subnets` output set?

Comment: why dont you just construct this id? its well-known anyway

Comment: @4c74356b41 Trying to make the code as portable as possible

Comment: how it would be less portable if you construct it? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, I think the problem you meet is that you cannot find the special one which you want to use from the outputs.

The possible means you could use as I think is to put the subnet Ids into a map with the subnet names. And then you can use the special subnet with the name and get it from the map. Here is the example code you can take a look:

```
variable "subnets" {
    type = list(string)
    default = [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ]
}

variable "subnet_prefix" {
    type = list(string)
    default = [
        "10.0.1.0/24",
        "10.0.2.0/24",
        "10.0.3.0/24"
    ]
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestVirtualNetwork1"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "East US"
  resource_group_name = "group_name"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
    count                                = length(var.subnets)
  name                 = element(var.subnets, count.index)
  resource_group_name  = "group_name"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefix       = element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index)
}

output "subnets_map" {
    value = zipmap(var.subnets, azurerm_subnet.example.*.id)
}
```

I see you use the modules, so you can put the output of the vnet module as an input for the VM modules.